# How to Log which AVPlayerItem is playing in AVQueuePlayer?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, avplayer, avqueueplayer

I'm using the AVQueuePlayer to play many audio files in sequence.

I need to log every AVPlayerItem that is playing.

How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AVQueuePlayer` has `currentItem` property. just log it every time item changed.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! Actually the currentItem property is from the AVPlayer, so AVQueuePlayer inherits from it.